# Como fazer a configuração da tag mvc resoures sem xml

Tags: java

Boa noite.

Estou tentando configurar a anotação do  sem xml, conforme o código abaixo, para adicionar minhas páginas js/css dentro, mas não estou conseguindo.

public class AppWebConfiguration {

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    // <mvc:resources mapping ="/resources/** location="/resources/"/>
    return resolver;
}
```

}

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // equivalents for <mvc:resources/> tags
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }
```

Para mais detalhes, veja essa resposta.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17013442/3137441